# MX and A Records with Google Apps

Tags: gmail, dns, mx-record, a-records

So I have this weird problem at my company with our email system.
(And I'll preface this by saying that I'm a web/graphic designer forced into an IT role as well, so forgive my noobish-ness please)

I just switched our company over to Google Apps for Business to take advantage of all of Google's apps and features.

The MX records for all six of our domains have been switched over to Google for days now, and it seems to be working very well except for a couple of things...

1. Those users in the organization who haven't switched their Outlook/Thunderbird/Mail App to Google's settings are still sending and receiving mail through the old system, which is hosted by MyHosting.com, even though the MX records clearly show that mail should be going to Google's servers.
2. Our website contact forms are still sending through the old system as well and NOT Google. For instance, woodshedsmokehouse.com contact form sends an email to info@woodshedsmokehouse.com on the old system, instead of sending it to info@woodshedsmokehouse.com at our Google Apps account (which is a 'nickname' of info@cheftimlove.com).

Now, here's where I think there might be some confusion... maybe, again I'm a noob.

All six of our domains have A Records of SMTP and MAIL that still point to MyHosting.com's mail servers.

Is this the issue? If so, how can I fix it? Google Apps support has not said a word about altering A Records

Any insight and help is more than greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand why it's sending through the old domain, but I can't understand the receiving part. Are the emails they are receiving through the old domain a "Reply To Email" Or "New Emails".

I know A records are used as backup MX Records. And MX record are not needed at all, if your hosting the mail server off the A record location.

I'm curious, if you found a solution and an explanation. I checked your [MX Records](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/mxrecords/) and they seem fine of the 2 domains you listed.  I also use MyHosting, but I host my own email servers.

If you can post the headers of the email on the ones they receive and send, that would be helpful.

Comment: I bit the bullet and contacted support. It was exactly as I thought. The local mail servers were interfering with any MX records, redirecting mail to it's own box instead of to the new Google servers. Sneaky little machines...